# Java - Mac os x - two versions

Tags: java, macos, operating-system, version

I recently updated my java version to "Java 8 update 77".

As far as i know, this is the newest version...

My Java Control Panel prints the same information,

but when i switch to terminal to verify the java version:

```
java -version
```

it outputs:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

When i type:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
```

it prints correctly:

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

So, did i anything wrong?
Why are there two different versions listed ?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal. Type...

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Search for `export JAVA_HOME`. When you find the line, comment it out by placing a `#` in front of the line.

Type on the next line...

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
```

assuming that is where the jdk is. Press `ctrl+o`, `ctrl+x`.

Type `source ~/.bash_profile`. And you should be all set.

The second option that you have written about is where you are checking the java applet plugin version which does not need to be the same as the jdk runtime environment.

Comment: hey, i installed "jdk_8u77" for mac and now it prints correct java version..no need to modify $JAVA_HOME. you know why?

Comment: it could be the case the the installer itself added the new path the `bash_profile`; you should check that.

Comment: @Creativecrypter made a small edit. i hope it answers your question.

Comment: @Creativecrypter Sure thing :)

Answer (score 2):

When Java is updated, it doesn't override the older version. It keeps the older version and also installs new version.

You have to change your $JAVA_HOME environment variable if you want to use new version.

This [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) May help

Comment: hey, i installed "jdk_8u77" for mac and now it prints correct java version..no need to modify $JAVA_HOME. you know why?

Answer (score 0):

To make your .bash_profile future proof, you can try this

export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"